# Scapy unable to fragment IPv6 packet

Tags: python, ipv6, scapy, ip-fragmentation

I am currently working on a project regarding IPv6 security. I'm trying to replicate the results found in this document found here: https://www.tno.nl/downloads/testing_the_security_of_IPv6_implementations.pdf

Scroll down to section 4.4, page 29.

I want to test whether creating packets with unlimited extension headers will in fact be able to crash a system. The problem I run in to again and again is that when running the script based on the documentation I keep getting the error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 787, in fragment
   return Scapy_Exception("cannot fragment this packet")
scapy.error.Scapy_Exception: cannot fragment this packet
```

And I need the packets to be fragmented. Otherwise I will not be able to create this endless stream of extension headers. I am testing this on a Debian 7 Wheezy system and using Python 2.7.

Here is the script I'm running:

```
from scapy.all import *

packet = IPv6(src="scrIP",dst="dstIP")
for x in range (0,100):
    packet = packet/IPv6ExtHdrDestOpt()/IPv6ExtHdrRouting()/IPv6ExtHdrHopByHop()

    send(packet)
```

I have been searching around but I cannot find anything with the same error. I hope someone can help.

Comment: Just a guess, but fragments in IPv6 work differently from IPv4. There is a fragment header required. Maybe you have to add it manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Klaus D. I tried adding the "IPv6ExtHdrFragment" option to the packet. Still doesn't work. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the version of scapy. The code work on my system (Ubuntu 14.04, scapy 2.2.0). Also try to run the code in the scapy shell as root:

```
$ sudo scapy 
Welcome to Scapy (2.2.0)
>>> p = IPv6(src='::1', dst='::1')
>>> for x in range(100): p = p/IPv6ExtHdrDestOpt()/IPv6ExtHdrRouting()/IPv6ExtHdrHopByHop()
... 
>>> send(p)
.
Sent 1 packets.
```

And of cause you have to replace `scrIP` and `dstIP` with real IPv6 adresses as strings.

Comment: Thanks for answering again. I am using scapy 2.2.0 and I am also running it as root. I just tried replicating your result and it does work when sending packets to localhost (::1), as it doesn't need to fragment the packets. When sending to another device on the network I get the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called scapy6:

http://www.secdev.org/conf/scapy-IPv6_HITB06.pdf

Try taking a look at page 128 and forward to see if you can get it to work, it should support IPv6.